# htaccess access subdomain subfolders

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I've created a subdomain `blog.example.co.uk` to point to a folder /blog in my root directory..
The folder blog has a subfolder /php which contain scripts that talk to my server eg login, logout.
This is my current structure;

root --> /blog --> /php

This is the rule that creates my subdomain

```
### Blog subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

The problem now is that files in /blog folder can't see files in /php.
I also get a file not found when I try the below;

```
http://blog.example.co.uk/php/login.php
```

How can I expose these files and be able to access them with the link above. I know I have to create a new rule just don't know how.

To access the scripts I have to point to below;

```
http://blog.example.co.uk/blog/php/login.php
```

I also want to exclude the php folder from any rewrites, I'm using the below but it doesn't work for the folder;

```
RewriteRule ^(/blog/php)($|/) - [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccss

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1
!^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js|font|woff|ttf|svg|eot|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```